# DirectX9, освещение текстурированной модели

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, direct3d

Все делаю по технологии: создаю буфер вершин, задаю координаты вершин, координаты текстуры, нормали. Без освещения модель отрисовывается идеально. А вот с освещением начинаются проблемы...На скриншоте видно, что происходит с моделью, которая попадает под освещение. Источник освещения находится справа сверху. Код материала и света:

```
    // Создаём материал и устанавливаем его в устройство
    D3DMATERIAL9 mat;
    ZeroMemory(&mat, sizeof(mat));
    mat.Ambient = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64));
    mat.Diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64));
    mat.Emissive = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0));
    mat.Specular = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64));
    mat.Power = 5.f;
    Device->SetMaterial(&mat);

    // Создаём источник света и устанавливаем его в системе
    D3DLIGHT9 point;
    ZeroMemory(&point, sizeof(point));
    point.Type = D3DLIGHT_POINT;
    point.Position = D3DXVECTOR3(30,15,-10);
    point.Ambient = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255, 255)) * 0.6f;
    point.Diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
    point.Specular = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255)) * 0.3f;
    point.Range = 1000.f;
    //point.Attenuation0 = 1.f;
    Device->SetLight(0, &point);
    Device->LightEnable(0, true);
    Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, true);
    Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, true);
    Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, true);
```

В чем моё непонимание? Спасибо.
P.S.: на самом деле, я не понимаю, как здесь участвует материал, но без материала освещение невозможно. Так как же правильно задать материал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действие specular, слишком явное, стоит откалибровать настройку этой составляющей.
Конкретно - правке подлежит коэффициент, на который умножается свет:

```
point.Specular = D3DXCOLOR(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255)) * 0.3f;
```

Здесь получается слишком высокое значение, поэтому засветы.

Comment: А если поподробнее? Для несведущих))